# re.sub not replacing words with punctuation

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

re.sub is replacing every occurrence of the desired word except for when the desired word ends with a punctuation.

I've tried using `r'\b' + word + '\b'`, `r'\b' + word + r'\W'`, `r'\b' + word + r'[\b.,!?]'`

Here is the full code:

```
import re
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
email_two = open("email_two.txt", "r").read()
email_three = open("email_three.txt", "r").read()
email_four = open("email_four.txt", "r").read()

def censor(phrase, email):
  phrasek = r'\b' + phrase + r'[\b.,!?]' 
  cemail = re.sub(phrasek, ('*'*(len(phrase))), email, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
  return cemail
def censor_plus(phrase_list, email):
  i = len(phrase_list)
  cemail = email
  while i >= 0:
    temail = censor(phrase_list[i-1],cemail)
    cemail = temail
    i = i-1
  return cemail
proprietary_terms = ['she', "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", 'her', "herself"]
#print(email_two)
#print(censor_plus(proprietary_terms, email_two))
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressing", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]
def neg_count(email, negs):
  neglist = []
  for neg in negs:
    match = re.search(neg,email_three)
    if match != None:
      neglist.append(match.span()[1])
    neglist.sort()
  return neglist
negind = neg_count(email_three,negative_words)
#print(email_three)
#print(censor_plus(proprietary_terms, email_three[:negind[1]] + censor_plus(negative_words,email_three[negind[1]:])))
censor_words = negative_words + proprietary_terms
def censor_bandf(words,email):
  split_email_line = email.split('\n')
  parts_to_join = []
  for i in range(len(split_email_line)):
    split_email = split_email_line[i].split()
    for j in range(len(words)):
      for k in range(len(split_email)):
        if split_email[k] == words[j]:
          split_email[k] = '*'*len(split_email[k])
          if k == 0:
            split_email[k+1] = '*'*len(split_email[k+1])
          elif k == len(split_email)-1:
            split_email[k-1] = '*'*len(split_email[k-1])
          else:
            split_email[k-1] = '*'*len(split_email[k-1])
            split_email[k+1] = '*'*len(split_email[k+1])
    parts_to_join.append(' '.join(split_email))
  return '\n'.join(parts_to_join)
#print(email_four)
print(censor_bandf(censor_words, email_four))
```

The output is:

SEND HELP!

Helena has sealed the entrances and exits to the lab. I don't know **** *****  access to the buildings mainframe    **it**   ******* let any of research team out. I'm cut off from the rest of the team here in my office. Helena has locked the doors, but I've managed to destroy the camera ** *** ***** see me in here. I don't think this email will even get out.

This all started when we tried to **** *** ******* for maintenance. ** ******* ** discover that we were unable to access to core personality matrix and when we tried to override the system manually a circuit blew, knocking Phil unconscious.

Helena is dangerous. She is completely unpredictable and cannot be allowed to escape this facility. So far she's been contained because the lab contains all ** *** ********** power, but ************   **mentioned before the lockdown that ** *** ****** ******* ****** billions of connected devices spanning the ***** *** ***** be able to vastly exceed the ********* *** *** here.

It's been four days now we've been trapped in here. I have no idea if anyone else is left alive. If anyone is reading this, cut the power to the whole building. It's the only way to stop her. Please help.

Francine

It replaces word but not when followed by a punctuation such as word. or word! or word? For example you can see words like help, her, and dangerous is part of the list but is not censored because it ends with . or !

Comment: You should be using a `\b` token on both sides, like this: https://regex101.com/r/A4l4jj/1 If you are still getting an unexpected result, post some examples so we can help you out.

Comment: also, please note that `[\b]` will match a backspace character, not a word break. You can't include word breaks in character classes.

Comment: You should be using `re.escape` on `phrase` before you use it as part of a regular expression: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: \b on both sides isn't working for some reason, I will post a more detailed example.

Comment: The punctuation in `phrase` is probably being treated as a special character in your regular expression. Again, use the previously mentioned `re.escape()` on `phrase` to avoid this.

Comment: I now see the silly mistake I made. When I wrote the latest function, I abandoned my previous sensor functions so for email_four I am not even calling censor or censor_plus so whatever I put there will not change anything. I will correct this and see if I get the output I need

Comment: Use `phrasek = r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(phrase))`

Answer (score -1):

I corrected my code and got the result I was looking for. Pasting below. I also pick up some neat tricks for future use from your comments. Thank you very much.

```
import re
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
email_two = open("email_two.txt", "r").read()
email_three = open("email_three.txt", "r").read()
email_four = open("email_four.txt", "r").read()

def censor(phrase, email):
  phrasek = r'\b' + re.escape(phrase) + r'\b'
  #print(phrasek)
  cemail = re.sub(phrasek, ('*'*(len(phrase))), email, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
  return cemail
def censor_plus(phrase_list, email):
  i = len(phrase_list)
  cemail = email
  while i >= 0:
    temail = censor(phrase_list[i-1],cemail)
    cemail = temail
    i = i-1
  return cemail
proprietary_terms = ['she', "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", 'her', "herself"]
#print(email_two)
#print(censor_plus(proprietary_terms, email_two))
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressing", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]
def neg_count(email, negs):
  neglist = []
  for neg in negs:
    match = re.search(neg,email_three)
    if match != None:
      neglist.append(match.span()[1])
    neglist.sort()
  return neglist
negind = neg_count(email_three,negative_words)
#print(email_three)
#print(censor_plus(proprietary_terms, email_three[:negind[1]] + censor_plus(negative_words,email_three[negind[1]:])))
censor_words = negative_words + proprietary_terms
def censor_bandf(words,email):
  split_email_line = email.split('\n')
  parts_to_join = []
  for i in range(len(split_email_line)):
    split_email = split_email_line[i].split()
    for j in range(len(words)):
      for k in range(len(split_email)):
        esc_word = re.escape(split_email[k]).split('\\')[0]
        if esc_word.lower() == words[j]:
          split_email[k] = censor(esc_word, split_email[k])
          if k == 0:
            split_email[k+1] = '*'*len(split_email[k+1])
          elif k == len(split_email)-1:
            split_email[k-1] = '*'*len(split_email[k-1])
          else:
            split_email[k-1] = '*'*len(split_email[k-1])
            split_email[k+1] = '*'*len(split_email[k+1])
    parts_to_join.append(' '.join(split_email))
  return '\n'.join(parts_to_join)
print(email_four)
print(censor_bandf(censor_words, email_four))
```